# Stray '\253' and '\307' in program C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote up a string of code that checks if a given number `n`, is prime or not, and returns true or false accordingly.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool primeChecker(int n) {
  int ul = n;
  int x;

  for (int f = 2; f < n; f++) {
    if (f >= ul) {
      break;
    }
    x = n % f;
    if (x == 0) {
      cout « n « " is not prime." « endl;
      return false;
    }
    else {
      ul = n/f+1;
    }
  }
  cout « n « " is prime." « endl;
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  int n = 90;

  cout « primeChecker(n) « endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it using cygwin with `g++ std=c++11 -o PrimeChecker.cpp` it gives me a whole lot of errors such as `stray '\253' in program` and `stray '\302' in program` on lines 15, 22, 30 (which are all the lines with the cout statements)

I do not understand what is wrong here. It looks to me as if I have everything written correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be using [a single Unicode character](http://unicodelookup.com/#%C2%AB/1):

```
«
```

where two less-than characters are expected:

```
<<
```

Comment: Yes! Please don't copy and paste code out of your word processor. That's just asking for trouble :-)